# Selecting with both indexes and boolean index

Tags: python, pandas

Apologies for the psuedo code, but I am on my phone and not home to do some testing.

I have been having a challenging time trying to splice (boolean index) and provide a list indexes. Depending on what I am doing with the resulting frame, I will get wildly unexpected results. I think what I have in the end of the post will work, but I want to understand the why.

So for example....

```
condition_1 = df['C'] > 100
indexes = df.groupby.get_group(['A']['B']).index
```

From my memory, the following doesn't work because the index doesn't align properly, but it may or may not give you an error depending what is using the data, such as matplotlib or event doing a .count().

```
df[condition_1].loc[indexes]
df.loc[indexes][condition_1]
```

Where I think I need to go is to stack the loc?

```
df.loc[condition_1].loc[indexes]
```

Is that the correct order? Now what if I need to set column D when that condition is met? Is this the right way because it doesn't make sense that it will.

```
df.loc[condition_1,'D'].loc[indexes] = True
```

Or should I try something like this?

```
indexes2 = df.loc[condition_1].loc[indexes].index
df.loc[indexes2, 'D' ] = True
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
grouped = df.groupby.get_group(['A']['B'])

indexes = grouped.loc[condition_1].index

df.loc[indexes, 'State'] = True
```